# NHibernate mapping not saving

Tags: nhibernate, mapping

I have the following Nhibernate XML file, edited to the core bits:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <hibernate-mapping assembly="TTP.DAO" namespace="TTP.DAO" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<class name="InitialProcessSetup" table="InitialProcessSetup" lazy="true" >
    <id name="SetupID" column="setupID" unsaved-value="0" type="System.Int32">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>
    <property name="DateCreated" column="DateCreated" />
    <many-to-one class="StoredUser" name="CreatedBy" column="CreatedBy" cascade="all-delete-orphan" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="OriginalDeadline" column="Deadline" />
    <property name="Detail" column="Detail" />
    <bag name="Subjects" table="InitialProcessSetupRatingSubject" inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="SetupId" not-null="true" />
        <many-to-many column="SubjectStoredUserId" class="StoredUser" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="Reviewers" table="InitialProcessSetupReviewer" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="SetupId" not-null="true" />
        <many-to-many column="ReviewerStoredUserId" class="StoredUser" />
    </bag>
    <bag name="Invitations" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key column="Setup" not-null="true"/>
        <one-to-many class="ProcessInvitation" />
    </bag>
</class>
```

I populate a new instance of the class indicated in the above mapping and save via GenericDAO().SaveOrUpdate(setup); and it saves the main object details but does not store the  bit.

On the class Subjects is defined as a virtual property that returns IList-StoredUser. The class constructor sets this property to a new List-StoredUser-().

The table indicated by the Subjects bag element is a pure mapping table that is it has a SetupID and StoredUserID column and that's it.

I add using a StoredUser to my derived StoredUserDAO() to the Subjects lists before saving. After the call to SaveOrUpdate() I also call Flush() as well.

In my database (SQL Server 2008R2) The main setup data is saved and the stored user I added to the Subjects list property is also saved it's just the mapping table does not get the setupID/StoredUserID added.

I'm a bit of a noob with Nhibernate and this is an existing project.
Any help ideas on what is wrong would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set inverse="true" for the Subjects collection. This implies that for NHibernate to create a record in the relation table, it must be the StoredUser that references the InitialProcessSetup.

Comment: Thanks so much. I really need to get a grip on NHibernate, unfortunately I haven't found the right Google terms to search for to get to some good docs. The best thing I've got is http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html which whilst it describes what you can put in the XML mapping it doesn't explain the whys very weel for me.